# Creating Swift iOS 9 Custom Keyboard using CollectionView and CollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So ive been looking all around for a guide on how to do this, and Im hitting blanks im afraid!

So basically I am wanting to create a simple emoji/image/gif keyboard extension for iOS using Swift.

For part of my main app, I have a viewController which contains a collectionView, with a collectionViewCell. Using info from a plist, I generate a collection of images(parent groups), and the when selected, it drills down to a second level showing all the images of that group. Selecting an image from this level copies the image to the clipboard.

So I have made this main app portion perfectly fine, and now want to mimic the functionality as a keyboard.

So I made a keyboard extension, which created a `class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController` file.
I then created a new view file, called `Keyboard.xib`. In the view, I added a `UICollectionView`.

In the `KeyboardViewController`, i then call

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "Keyboard", bundle: nil)
    let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)

    view = objects[0] as! UIView

    addKeyboardButtons()
}
```

Which, when the app runs, shows my empty collectionView in the keyboard view.

My challenge now is to populate the collectionView with a reusable cell which will show an image from a names in a plist file.

In my main app, I was able to determine the number of items in the collectionView, which created a cell for me.

[image]

However, in the keyboard view, I dont have that option to add a cell. Dragging a cell into the collectionView doesnt help either.

[image]

So Im just wondering, what would be the best way to get a reusable cell into my collectionView in the `Keyboard.xib`, which I can then populate with images?

I read somewhere from an older post that a person created a new `xib` file, purely as his cell which contained an `imageView`, and used that `xib` cell file to populate in the `collectionView`.

I've created that additional `xib` file, but unsure on how to make the connection to have it be used in the collectionView as a resuable cell...

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Try include your collectionView data source

Comment: And the steps you have taken to register the Cell nibs

Comment: Im cant seem to, else unsure how to, create a outlet to the collectionView from the `Keyboard.xib` file. I cant 'drag' an IBOutlet connection to the controller... unless im approaching it wrong?

Comment: You mean something like this http://bcdilumonline.blogspot.co.za/2015/03/add-uicollectionview-to-xib-with-custom.html

Comment: There is no 'outlet' from the cell to the controller. The cell Xib will connect to a cell subclass. The connection is done programmatically via `registerNib`

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by creating a new class file for my `Keyboard.xib`, and creating and setting the collectionView outlet and delegates in there.

```
class KeyboardView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: MyCollectionView!

    class func instanceFromNib() -> KeyboardView {
        return UINib(nibName: "Keyboard", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! KeyboardView
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print("awaking from nib")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("adding numberOfItemsForSection")
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("adding cell")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
       print("setting size..")
       return CGSizeMake(320, 350)
    }
}
```

And then update my `KeyboardViewController.swift` file to instantiate like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let keyboardView = KeyboardView.instanceFromNib()
    keyboardView.collectionView.registerNib(UINib.init(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    self.view.addSubview(keyboardView)

    addKeyboardButtons()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried this code, but the keyboard will not load.  Do you have the project posted anywhere online?  I have been stuck on this for a long time :(  Thanks!

Comment: @theMouse : Were you able to solve the issue. I am having quite a unique problem. I am getting SIGQUIT everytime I try to deque the cell 
my setup is fairly simple as I am making POC. KeyboardViewController is datasource and delegate for collection view.